# How can I pass dynamic data to a link in laravel inertia

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I wanted to get something like a view more page to my project and i want to pass dynamic data from my backend to the link router to be able to get a view more page for that exact record.
Eg.

```html
<Link :href="route('viewproduct')" class="btn" style="background: #24882c; color: white;">View more</Link>


{{ product.id }}
```

i want to be able to pass data to the link that would make it look like this: `/viewproduct/1`

i have tried passing data to it like using the data attribute, but it still didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can pass dynamic data to a link using route parameters. Assuming you have a route defined,

```
Route::get('/viewproduct/{productId}', 'ProductController@show')->name('viewproduct');
```

In your Vue component, you can use the route helper to generate the URL with the dynamic data (productId) and pass it to the Link component:

```
<template>
  <Link :href="getProductViewLink(product.id)" class="btn" style="background: #24882c; color: white;">View more</Link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    product: Object // Assuming you are passing the product object as a prop to this component
  },
  methods: {
    getProductViewLink(productId) {
      return this.route('viewproduct', { productId });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: according to the recent error is saying id parameter is required